# Put jQuery fonctione inside featherlight.js

Tags: featherlight.js

Im using featherlight.js
Inside the lightbox content I put a simple jQuery fonction.
A button which show a div when I click on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button-popup").click(function () {
        $("#reveal").show("slow");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjavi7/JNsu6/26/).

Comment: *it doen't work* What is the error message? Please add more information in your question. Can you provide a working example on JSFiddle?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Here it is:
https://jsfiddle.net/fjavi7/JNsu6/26/

Comment: It works for me, I click on `<a class=".button-popup" ...>` and it shows the `<div id="reveal">`.

Comment: Really?!! Not working for me...

Comment: In fact, the `<div id="reveal">` only appears if: I open the lightbox, then I close it with the cross, and I reopen the lightbox. When `<div id="reveal">` is supposed to appear?

Comment: Try [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/28/), you can see that the `click` event is triggered, but it seems that `featherlight.js` hides the content of the lightbox, you should check that `featherlight.js` doesn't change the style of the lightbox.

Comment: Thank you for yout answer I'm goint to investigate further.

Comment: Still not working. I can't find the solution.